# Use request.user for model deserialization in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

Lets say i have a ToDo Model like this:

```
class ToDo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserModel)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

And i'm using django rest framework for my API. Then i'll have this for the serializer:

```
class ToDoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ToDo
        fields = ('text', 'id', 'user')
```

and this for the `ViewSet`:

```
class ToDoResponder(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    model = ToDo
    def get_queryset(self):
        return ToDo.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
    serializer_class = ToDoSerializer
```

As i'm using `TokenAuthentication` and `get_queryset()` the user can only see his own Todos. Unfortunately i can send ToDos and fake the user field so i could spam the ToDo List of another user. I don't want that.

How can i tell `django-rest-framework` to use `request.user` for specific fields like 'user' in the most DRY/Pythonic way? After all this is no exotic requirement and should be reused.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the drf doc http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions you can find a solution creating a new permission:

```
from rest_framework import permissions


class IsOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj.user == request.user
```

at this point you can use it in your `ToDoResponder`

```
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsOwner)
```

In the same page in your `ToDoResponder`:

```
def pre_save(self, obj):
    obj.user = self.request.user
    super(ToDoResponder, self).pre_save(obj)
```

Comment: Thanks that should work but i am still looking for another solution since i'd like to use `request.user` as the default value for `user` so the client don't has to send the user id.

Comment: Exactly what i want! One note: i had to remove 'user' from the fields list in the serializer otherwise pre_save() will not be called

Comment: You could add `editable=False` to `user = models.ForeignKey(UserModel)` if a ToDo Entry can't change the owner

Comment: that does not work for me. neither for this guy https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-rest-framework/jjBuuImMADw

Comment: Did you try with `user = models.ForeignKey(UserModel, blank=True)`?

Comment: Leads to ValueError: Cannot assign None: "ToDo.user" does not allow null values. But i would consider changing it to blank=True or null=True bad practice because the model needs a valid user from the datastructure point of view